# WPF datagrid multi Tier Header, editing cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

So I have a multi tier header, that is basically just a header with two sub headers underneath it,
the code for the look of the header is:

```
<Style x:Key="PlateDetailsmultitier" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyleBase2Tier}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="Root" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="49" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="24" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="49"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="49"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="Plate Details" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MouseDown="ContentPresenter_MouseDown"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="t__plate" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   MouseDown="ContentPresenter_MouseDown"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1"  Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <ContentPresenter  Content="&#963;y" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   MouseDown="ContentPresenter_MouseDown"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1"  Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1"  Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But the problem is that when I go to try to edit these cells it just selects both columns as one cell, and i can not edit either of these columns.

I would like to be able to edit both columns seperatly.
To start off datagrid template column I just used

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource PlateDetailsmultitier}" Width="100">
```

Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem.